# How to open multiple app play store link one after another

Tags: android

I came across an app that is [My Jio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jio.myjio). After downloading the app it shows a screen with bunch of apps to download and after you click on install all you will be redirected to the play store to install the first app you have to explicitly press install button. After the install is finished it automatically redirects you to the play store link of another app and so on. After all the apps are installed it redirects you to the app. Our client need this kind of functionality. So, anybody has any idea how to implement it.

What we did is normal coding that only redirects to only one apps link

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Comment: Check for callback using [StartAcitivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)